# Middleware not being called when defining the metadataAddress property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, identityserver3, openid-connect

I am configuring a asp.net mvc app (or relying party) to use thinktecture identity server. Identity Server is up and running locally and I am able to retrieve metadata from its endpoint.

Here is the code used to register the middleware:

```
  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions("localIdp")
            {
                AuthenticationType = "localIdp",                
                ClientId = "Welfare4Partners",
                MetadataAddress = "https://localhost:44333/core/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                //Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
                //{
                //    AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/authorize",
                //    JwksUri = "https://localhost:44333/core/.well-known/jwks",
                //    TokenEndpoint = "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/token",
                //    UserInfoEndpoint = "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/userinfo",
                //    Issuer = "https://localhost:44333/core",
                //    EndSessionEndpoint = "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/endsession",
                //},                
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(context);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(context);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(context);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                        context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                        return Task.FromResult(context);
                    },
                    MessageReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(context);
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(context);
                    }
                },

                Authority = "https://localhost:44333",
                RedirectUri = AppSettings.PostLoginRedirectUri,                
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken,
                Scope = "openid",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType                
            });
```

As you can see I have commented the Configuration property once I have the MetadataAddress prop set.

I am calling the middleware with the following line of code in an Action:

```
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = AppSettings.PostLoginRedirectUri, IsPersistent = false, };                
                OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge(authProperties, authenticationType);
```

I have verified the value of the authenticationType and it contains "localIdp". After calling the challenge nothing happens. Odd think is that if I comment the metadataAddress and uncomment the Configuration property, the middleware is called.

Is there a way to debug the OWIN requests in order to check what's wrong in the code?

Metadata is the following:

```
    {
        "issuer": "https://localhost:44333/core",
        "jwks_uri": "https://localhost:44333/core/.well-known/jwks",
        "authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/authorize",
        "token_endpoint": "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/token",
        "userinfo_endpoint": "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/userinfo",
        "end_session_endpoint": "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/endsession",
        "check_session_iframe": "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/checksession",
        "revocation_endpoint": "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/revocation",
        "introspection_endpoint": "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/introspect",
        "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
        "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
        "scopes_supported": ["openid", "profile", "email", "address", "roles", "all_claims", "offline_access", "read", "write"],
        "claims_supported": ["sub", "name", "family_name", "given_name", "middle_name", "nickname", "preferred_username", "profile", "picture", "website", "gender", "birthdate", "zoneinfo", "locale", "updated_at", "email", "email_verified", "address", "role"],
        "response_types_supported": ["code", "token", "id_token", "id_token token", "code id_token", "code token", "code id_token token"],
        "response_modes_supported": ["form_post", "query", "fragment"],
        "grant_types_supported": ["authorization_code", "client_credentials", "password", "refresh_token", "implicit", "custom2", "custom"],
        "subject_types_supported": ["public"],
        "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
        "code_challenge_methods_supported": ["plain", "S256"],
        "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["client_secret_post", "client_secret_basic"]
    }
```